# Maximize window in XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, maximize

I am currently using the following code to allow the user to resize and maximize the window:

```
Window.AllowUserResizing = true; 
Window.ClientSizeChanged += Window_ClientSizeChanged;
```

with the `Window_ClientSizeChanged` event handling the changes and re-scaling the drawn images etc.

This allows me to resize the window however much I want and also maximize it using the standard button in the window's handle. I would like to be able to start the application with the window in its maximized mode but can't figure out how to do so. I know I can use `graphics.IsFullScreen = true;` to show it in full screen mode but I would like to be able to run the program in a maximized, windowed mode. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can put this code in the constructor to do what you want:**

```
Form form = (Form)Control.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

This requires that you add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` to your project.

This does have the downside that it actually sets up the graphics device twice on startup. Once in the normal way, and then once again because the window was resized. (Although this all happens before the form is first displayed.)

It has the advantage of being extremely simple to implement.

---

<strike>I'm going to poke around for awhile and see if the initialisation order can be changed...</strike>

There really is no simple way to get around this problem, it would seem.

Comment: I've seen this answer a couple of times and couldn't get it to work. Didn't realize I had to actually add a new reference in the solution explorer. The answers I've seen said to just add `using System.Windows.Forms` to the top of the main class. Let me know if you find the fix for the dual startup. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Turns out to be very much a problem for the too-hard basket. Potentially involves a lot of win32 fiddling around.

Comment: Ah probably out of the scope of my project. Maybe something to look into in future more larger ones where it may cause a few problems.