# MonoGame Maximize window event

Tags: c#, mono, xna, monogame

I have been having trouble trying to implement an event using monogame and c#. Currently when my window is resized i call an event:

```
        this.Window.ClientSizeChanged += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Window_ClientSizeChanged);

        void Window_ClientSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int width = Window.ClientBounds.Width;
            int height = Window.ClientBounds.Height;
            if (width > 0 && height > 0)
            {
                graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = width;
                graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = height;
                graphics.ApplyChanges();
             }
        }
```

This is all fine and resizes my window correctly and updates the width/height. However it is not triggered in the event that my window is resized via a user clicking the maximize/minimize button on the window frame.

After spending some time looking into some solutions the only suggestion to implement a maximize event was from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717084/maximize-window-in-xna-4-0):

```
Form form = (Form)Control.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

However this is a solution im not particularly fond of as it relies on the inclusion of **System.Windows.Forms** and since i may one day want to build for other platforms id rather not include any specific windows libraries.

Is there any monogame functionality that handles the maximize/minimize event calls for each platform or is it up to the end user to implement such functionality?

Comment: Windows Forms is supported on multiple plattforms via Mono, depending on what plattform you want to support, this migh not even be a problem http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've also had this issue and haven't found any 'built in' solution for that in the MonoGame API.

The solution I came up with was performing a check at the start of each frame on whether the width and height of `Window.ClientBounds` were changed.
It detects all window resizes similarly to the `Window.ClientSizeChanged` event, but also detects resizes made by maximizing/restoring the window.

Comment: Both your answer and the comment are correct however i chose to implement your suggestion as it seemed more modifyable should the codebase change. However it seems either way if you want to recreate a particular resolution and window state (maximized or minimized) then you need to use winforms....annoyingly...as it seems the only way to ensure its the correct size + maximized. Either way a helpful solution! thanks

Comment: Note that when the client minimizes, you will have a ClientBounds of (0, 0, 0, 0) so take that into account if you are checking on every Update.

Comment: @Acidic, did almost the exact thing you did. Only difference is I used the Update and introduced a delay, so the check is two times per second. Not sure what your use case was, but for me, I had to change some display ratios to rescale properly my content. Didn't need this check to be that fast. Thanks for your post, I found it after I banged my head a bit and already resolved it, but it's a nice confirmation. :)